# Help show a limit

Tags: limits

Can anyone help to show 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt {2\pi} x - x\int_{-\infty}^x {e^{ - \frac{{{t^2}}}{2}}}dt}{\exp\left( - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)} = 1.$$ Thanks!

Comment: L'Hospital rule does not work ??

Comment: Since no post leading to the answer was posted so far, here is a detailed hint: first note that  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ -t^2/2}dt=\sqrt{2\pi},$$ hence the numerator is actually $$G(x)=x\int_x^{+\infty}e^{ -t^2/2}dt.$$ To evaluate $G(x)$ when $x\to+\infty$, use the change of variable $t=x+s/x$ to get $$G(x)=xe^{-x^2/2}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-s-s^2/(2x^2)}x^{-1}ds\sim e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-s}ds= e^{-x^2/2}.$$ Thus, the desired limit is $$1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt {2\pi} x - x\int_{-\infty}^x {e^{ - \frac{{{t^2}}}{2}}}dt}{\exp\left( - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt {2\pi}  - \int_{-\infty}^x {e^{ - \frac{{{t^2}}}{2}}}dt}{\frac{1}{x}\exp\left( - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)}\text{ , is of the form }\frac{0}{0}$$as , $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt=\sqrt{2\pi}$

So , we can easily apply L'Hospital rule.

Now , $$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}-\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-t^2/2}\,dt-\int_0^xe^{-t^2/2}\,dt}{\frac{1}{x}\exp(-x^2/2)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{-e^{-x^2/2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-x^2/2}-e^{-x^2/2}}\text{ applying L'Hospital rule.}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}=1.$$

Comment: And... how to deduce the value of L or even that L exists from this approach?

Comment: An example... $ $

Comment: Well...Show my mistake without wasting time

Comment: It seems there are no mistake, now that you completed your answer. Well done.

Comment: Why you edit your comment below the question?

Comment: Because I found a smoother way to do things. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: In your comment ( below question ) your answer was $\sqrt{2\pi}$ and that's why  I commented that it is given to prove the limit is 1 '

Comment: Ok...By the way you was wrong NOT I.